# Count several tables and return data in multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to learn SQL and currently I'm learning about the COUNT function. I want to test pulling data from multiple tables and i want to return a result set like:

```
| tablename | row_count |
| Computers | 2000      |
| Buildings | 37        |
```

So far I haven't figured out a way to pull the info and make a view like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a union and a count(*) with a (constant) label:

```
select 'Computers' as tablename, count(*) as row_count from Computers
union all
select 'Buildings' as tablename, count(*) as row_count from Buildings
```

Note that using `union all` (instead of just `union`) means that rows returned will stay in the order they are selected in the query.

Comment: +1 but to make it equal equal to the OP request you should have given aliases to the columns :-)

Comment: You meant `from Computers ` and `from Buildings`, right? They are the table names

Comment: @Icarus Technically the name of the tables wasn't given by the OP. What he gave was labels. An old school db could have named them `tblComputers` and `tblBuildings`

Comment: @xanatos the way I understood the question is that the OP wants to know how many records are there in table Computers and in table Buildings. That's why I made my comment. So I was expecting `select 'Computers' as tablename, count(*) from Computers UNION ALL select 'Buildings' as tablename, count(*) from Buildings`

Comment: @Icarus Be aware that (from what I know) DB2 has a strange syntax for columns aliases. `'Computers' "tablename", count(*) "row_count"`

Comment: @xanatos I see, but you know what I meant.

Comment: @Icarus Yes, and you are right. But I'm of the school of thought "s##t in, s##t out". It's the work of the questioner to give the details :-)

Comment: Bohemian got it! thanks so much. i kept thinking how i was going to work having multiple from's etc but i totally forgot all about the union :( how silly

Comment: Thanks to all comments - I have improved the answer

Comment: Are you sure of this: "Note that using union all (instead of just union) means that rows returned will stay in the order they are selected in the query."? In the tsql dialect it isn't specified, and I would think a UNION ALL would be a good point for multiple servers to combine their data for big queries without having to collect them all first.

Comment: I'll add that, at least on Oracle, it seems to be an undocumented "feature" (http://plsql-challenge.blogspot.com/2011/07/union-all-and-sorting-first-objection.html)